# charts from one google spreadsheet to another dynamically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
Google spreadsheet A with "sheet 1" - Master spreadsheet
Google spreadsheet B with "sheet 1"
```

There are charts in sheet B with source data in it. I want to import the chart to master spreadsheet B in such a way that, when the chart changes in sheet B, it should dynamically change in master sheet A too.

After a lot of research, I was able to find below:

1. Importrange - imports the data only, and not charts
2. copying the chart itself and pasting it to master sheet A, but it doesn't get changed when the chart is changing dynamically in sheet B.
3. publishing the chart and inserting the URL as an image - this doesn't work if the master sheet A is google spreadsheet, but works for google docs, slides, etc. (correct me if I am wrong, as I tried and threw me an error)

For ease of explanation, I have given only two spreadsheets as an example. In the real case, I have one mastersheet, and 6 separate spreadsheets.

Any alternative suggested, or help is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share sample example spreadsheets? It makes it easier to help when you do not have to create the example from scratch.

Comment: I went ahead and created the sample files. Your data range for sheet A might not be correct. 

Sheet A: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MmRih-mjFTC2_nrHPNG0Z3oJtd9ncKlGAJBIqvbraqM/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet B: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rFpTghMxWuNElxxnSD4_nWHaxQDofGUcNsE2VqR6sHc/edit?usp=sharing

On adding new entries in Spreadsheet B table, chart in Spreadsheet A is dynamically updated

Comment: @urwaCFC, Thanks a lot for your response, and efforts of putting together sample spreadsheets. I will keep that in mind to create sample sheets in future questions. 
I see what you have done, and i was able to achieve that myself(my bad, i didnt mention in my question). What i am trying to achieve here is, instead of importing the data from sheet B to A, i just want to directly use the source data from sheet B, and just create the chart in sheet A.

Comment: In other words, just the chart should be present in sheet A, and should pick up source directly from sheet B. The reason, the data from sheet B is huge, and i am planning on keeping close to 8 charts similar from different sheets(B,C,D,F,G,H). The mastersheet is slowed down due to enormous data. 
As a last resort i had planned to do the same you have demonstrated above(thanks a bunch once again), but i am still trying to see if there are any alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know your task but I found the answer to your question by using IMPORTAGE for data, then show the chart and hide the list where the data are shown

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place an answer to a question, try to explain a little bit. In fact you did not explain anything.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your main concern is the size of the data set in "sheet B" bogging down your sheet where you want your charts to live.  Assuming the sheet with the charts is likely a dashboard of some sort that many individuals will use somewhat often so you want good performance and also likely want to limit how many hands have access to the master data set for various reasons.

Depending on what you are exactly trying to chart, and also what your data set looks like or is structured like and also the type of data it contains, a possible option is to use google sheets query formula along with importrange.  This will pull only the data that you need to make the chart.  Unless I've missed something somewhere, at the very least you will need to pull in the data you want to make the chart from.  Using this method allows you to have dynamic data pulls from a master sheet in order to build and keep up to date the charts you want on what I'll call  your dashboard sheet.

Take a look at this example that I used recently to provide a dynamic data table in a user dashboard that is pulled from a sheet with a roughly 3 million cell count data set that runs slow as hell if you try to chart/pivot/parse any kind of data within that same file.

Depending on your exact needs, your formula may be more complex or more simple.  But, this basic framework should hopefully help you out a bit.

Here is the full formula, which we will break down further below:

```
=QUERY(
      QUERY(
        {
         IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!A2:A"),
         IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!C2:C"),
         IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!L2:L"),
         IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!M2:M"),
         IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!AG2:AG"),
         IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!AH2:AH"),
         IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!AD2:AD") 
        },
        "SELECT Col2, Col4, SUM(Col5), SUM(Col6)
         WHERE Col3 = 'A/R Invoice' 
         AND Col4 <= date '"&TEXT(DataValidation!I2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
         AND Col4 >= date '"&TEXT(DataValidation!I2 - G2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
         AND (Col7 = 'Brand A')
         GROUP BY Col2, Col4"
      ),
      "SELECT Col1, SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4), COUNT(Col2) 
       GROUP BY Col1
       ORDER BY SUM(Col4) DESC
       LABEL 
         Col1 'Account Name',
         SUM(Col3) 'Total CE',
         SUM(Col4) 'Total Rev',
         COUNT(Col2) 'Unique Invoices'"
    )
```

This formula is pulling from a large sales data set that each row is built from each line item from every sales invoice for every product we have sold over a couple year period of time.  The columns are everything from customer account name, date, sales, rep, product brand family, brand name, package family, item name, sku, quantity in units, quantity in case equivalents, quantity in bbls(we are a brewery), quantity in gallons, unit revenue, unit COGS, unit GP, total revenue, total COGS, total GP, etc.....This formula pulls data to create a table that shows Account names, Total units(Case Equivalents in this situation), Total Revenue, and the number of unique purchases(each different date would be a unique purchase) the account made during the time period.

Let's break this down by sections what is going on here.

The user can select the number of days they want to look back from the date the master data set was last updated, which is usually weekly on Monday.

The date the master data set was last updated is in cell 'DataValidation!I2' on the user's sheet.  This value actually imports using importrange from a cell on the  master sheet which uses a simple =max(Data!M2:M) formula to return the most recent date value from the data set.

The user enters the number of days they want to look back into cell G2 on the user's sheet, which then calculates the starting date for the data we are trying to compile.  We work this out in the WHERE clause below. For this we are selecting only rows that came from A/R Invoices(column L in my master sheet is where the document type that row of data came from is designated ).  The data set also contains information from Credit Memos and a couple other document types.  We then work out the start and end dates we want to consider with the two Col4 lines. The I2-G2 is last update date, or end date,  minus number of days to looks back, which gives us the start date. The Col7 part of the WHERE clause is selecting this particular Brand we are looking at for this user.  We could put a dropdown menu in a cell and reference that cell also if we wanted to make the whole thing brand dynamic.

```
WHERE Col3 = 'A/R Invoice' 
         AND Col4 <= date '"&TEXT(DataValidation!I2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
         AND Col4 >= date '"&TEXT(DataValidation!I2 - G2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
         AND (Col7 = 'Brand A')
```

Now, in my use case I need to first pull a certain set of columns to parse via WHERE and Group By clauses, and then query that data again to get to my final resulting table of data.  The reason for this is I want to get to the exact set of data that matches my date range and apply some grouping to it before then counting the number of unique dates each customer account purchase this brand.

The below is the inner query where I am pulling only certain columns from my master data sheet that relate to this exact task.  So the array of imported columns is the range for this section of the query.  Notice that the column identifiers are now relative to this array.  No matter where the column was in the original data, they are now (in this case) Col1, Col2, Col3.... to Col7 (Data!A2:A=Col1, Data!AD2:AD=Col7).  Notice that I am applying a WHERE clause to Data!M2:M(now Col3), but I am not selecting it as data to display.  I still need to importrange on it though to apply the WHERE clause to it.

From my master sheet, Column A is the name of the distributor partner.  Column C is the Retail Account Name the product was sold to.  Column L is the document type(Invoice, Credit Memo, etc...). Column M is the document date.  Column AG is the total quantity in case equivalents. Column AH is total revenue. Column AD is the brand name of the product.

```
QUERY(
    {
     IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!A2:A"),
     IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!C2:C"),
     IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!L2:L"),
     IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!M2:M"),
     IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!AG2:AG"),
     IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!AH2:AH"),
     IMPORTRANGE("your master sheet url", "Data!AD2:AD") 
    },
    "SELECT Col2, Col4, SUM(Col5), SUM(Col6)
     WHERE Col3 = 'A/R Invoice' 
     AND Col4 <= date '"&TEXT(DataValidation!I2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
     AND Col4 >= date '"&TEXT(DataValidation!I2 - G2, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
     AND (Col7 = 'Brand A')
     GROUP BY Col2, Col4"
  ),
```

At this point I have a table that would look like so -

| Retail Account Name | Document Date | Quantity CE | Revenue Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data | Data | Data | Data |

This table now becomes the range for the outer query part below.  Notice now the columns get renumbered again because they are now based on the above table structure.  We will now select the account name, quantity CE, total revenue, and then only count the unique dates each account made a purchase.

```
"SELECT Col1, SUM(Col3), SUM(Col4), COUNT(Col2) 
           GROUP BY Col1
           ORDER BY SUM(Col4) DESC
           LABEL 
             Col1 'Account Name',
             SUM(Col3) 'Total CE',
             SUM(Col4) 'Total Rev',
             COUNT(Col2) 'Unique Invoices'"
        )
```

The final resulting data table look like the one below.  Which, you could then make a chart from.  For my use case the resulting table was sufficient for my needs, but could easily become the data range for a dynamic chart if I wanted it to.

Final column structure of my resulting data table after importing individual columns from a large master data set and then applying a query function to it to filter and group the data a certain way before then using the result of that as the range for a second query:

| Retail Account Name | Quantity CE | Total Revenue | Unique Invoices |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Data | Data | Data | Data |

This table shows the Total CE and Total Revenue from every single row in the date range for each account that purchased that brand of product and also how many different times they made a purchase during the date range.  Keep in mine my master data set contains hundreds and hundreds of accounts purchasing many different package sizes and types across hundreds of different brands and sub brands over a several year period of time.  There are tens of thousands of rows and something like 45 columns. Hopefully this example helps you out, or helps out somebody who stumbles across this in the future who might have the same or similar application they are trying to do.